# Java printing in new line, which I don't want

Tags: java

```
for (int numToCheck = start; numToCheck < numSteps*increment + start; 
            numToCheck += increment)
    {
        System.out.println(numToCheck+"\t");
        String tekst = getStringFromFile(textfile, numToCheck);

        double beg1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i<trials; i++) {
            BasicDocument doc = new BasicDocument(tekst);
            doc.getFleschScore();
        }

        double time1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - beg1;
        System.out.println(time1+"\t");

        double beg2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i<trials; i++) {
            EfficientDocument doc2 = new EfficientDocument(tekst);
            doc2.getFleschScore();              
        }

        double time2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - beg2;
        System.out.println (time2);
```

This is the code I'm running, and the results are printed in new lines, not separated by tabs (\t).

What am I not understanding?

Also, anything else you can give me advice about, I have started programming just recently, does the code look good?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
System.out.print()
```

not

```
System.out.println()
```

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) of `println()`

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
System.out.println(time1+"\t");
```

to

```
System.out.print(time1+"\t");
```

`println` **always** adds a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`System.out.print()` with `\t`

`\t` will add a tab and `print()` method will print on the same line so you will be
having your output separated by tab.